# Concatenate date, text and cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to create a description that includes the Month/Year, text, and the value of a cell. I have tried two methods and neither one is working for me.

First i tried this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=CONCATENATE(Format(DateAdd("m", -1, now), "mmmyy"), " My Text ",RC[-19])"
```

Which gives a

> run-time error 1004.

Next I tried

```
Range("X10").Value = Format(DateAdd("m",-1,now), "mmmyy") & " My Text " & E10
```

Which output the date and the text but not the value of the cell.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. Searching on here got me to this point, but I'm stuck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you mean `Range("E10").Value`?

Comment: For your second equation, it should be `" My Text " & Range("E10")`

Comment: if you are going to use a formula then they must use formula: `"=CONCATENATE(TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1), ""mmmyy""), "" My Text "",RC[-19])"`

Comment: Maybe `E10` is blank?

Comment: @ScottCraner I get the same run-time error on this.

Comment: @braX That worked, but if I wanted to copy that down so it gave the value relative to the row, what would I use.

Comment: I get no error with `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=CONCATENATE(TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1), ""mmmyy""), "" My Text "",RC[-19])"`  I deleted my old comment that was wrong.  Make sure you try the new one.

Comment: Looks like Scott has it covered.

Comment: @ScottCraner That worked! I was missing the double quotes. How do I mark this as answered. First time asking something.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
'Let: X be your Workbook index, Y be your sheet index, YY be your row index, XX be your column index
Sub macro2()
     MsgBox Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date) & " " & Workbooks(X).Sheets(Y).Cells(YY, XX).Value
End Sub
```

All of these may be stored into a string variable for portability across your project.

Good luck!.